# Projections in EF7

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm try to do the following simple projection in Entity Framework 7 and getting the error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=When called from 'VisitMethodCallExpression', expressions of type 'Expression' can only be replaced with other non-null expressions of type 'Expression'.
  Source=Remotion.Linq
```

Here is the code:

```
            //try simple projection with linq syntax
            var blogSummaries1 = blogContext.Blogs.Select(blog => new
            {
                Id = blog.Id,
                Name = blog.Name,
                PostCount = blog.Posts.Count()
            }).ToList();
            //That threw

            //try simple projection with query syntax
            var blogSummaries2 = (from blog in blogContext.Blogs
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Id = blog.Id,
                                     Name = blog.Name,
                                     PostCount = blog.Posts.Count()
                                 }).ToList();
            //That threw
```

The same code works on EF 6.

I can do this in EF 7 and get all the data loaded:

```
var blogs = blogContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).ToList();
```

So I don't think it is a general configuration issue.

Is support for projections not included in EF 7 yet?

Comment: You don't want to use `Include( b => b.Posts )` as that will make EF load all rows in the relation instead of performing `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you [create an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new)?